# Hadoop 2 - MapReduce Issue using PIG over hadoop

Tags: mapreduce, cassandra, apache-pig, hadoop2

Im facing an issue while running a MapReduce program using Hadoop 2 (YARN) and Pig. I'm able to read data from Cassandra using Pig script, however when running MapReduce, it is throwing the exception as given below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(ColumnFamilyOutputFormat.java:80)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator$InputOutputFileVisitor.visit(InputOutputFileValidator.java:80)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOStore.accept(LOStore.java:66)
```

Answer (score 0):

The binary distribution of Pig is compiled against Hadoop 1.x. You need to recompile it against 2.x (2.2 in my case) to get it to work. Try this:

```
ant clean jar-withouthadoop -Dhadoopversion=23
```

([source](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201310.mbox/%3CCAOehgTkFR7FfCxsfqwZWwaWWc7xDoiYpVEF-q4dg+2WRC8LCNA@mail.gmail.com%3E))